# What is the name for each angle in polar coordinates on three dimensions

Tags: polar-coordinates

In polar coordinates each point can be defined by its radius and two angles: $(r,\theta ,\varphi )$, the relationship with the cartesian coordinates can vary but I would use:

$$x=r\sin(\theta)\cos(\varphi) $$
$$y=r\sin(\theta)\sin(\varphi) $$
$$z=r\cos(\theta) $$

I would like to know the name of this angles. I have seen that $\varphi$ is called colatitude or zenith but $\theta$ is just referred as "the angle".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short and sweet, here's what I've been calling them :

$\theta$ is "polar angle" or "colatitude" $\in [0,\pi]$ (indeed the regular latitude $\in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$)

$\varphi$ is "azimuth" or "longitude" $\in [0,2\pi]$

I have seen french people call $\theta$ the "zenithal angle" but only rarely

Answer (score 1):

I call your $\theta$ the [zenith angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenith#Angle) and your $φ$ the [azimuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuth).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) offers more suggestions.